# Appium: unable to find an element, what is that i am missing

Tags: appium, appium-android

I am a beginner in using Appium automation and I am facing a problem where I am unable to find an element in the below test code, please help me understand on what i am missing.

> Java

```
    public class Main {

    AndroidDriver driver = null;

    @Before
    public void main(){
        DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities();
        cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, "00757fccdb6fabc5");
        cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_NAME, "Android");
        cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APP, "C:\\Users\\kswamina\\Desktop\\zApp1\\zApp1\\zApp1\\build\\outputs\\apk\\debug\\zApp1-debug.apk");

        try {
            driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), cap);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void testClick(){
        if(driver != null){

            try {
                Thread.sleep(3000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            WebDriverWait wait0 = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
            wait0.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(MobileBy.id("com.example.app1:id/tvKey"))).sendKeys("MMS");

            driver.findElement(By.id("com.example.app1:id/etName")).sendKeys("VPN");
            driver.findElement(By.id("com.example.app1:id/btnStore")).click();
            WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 2);
            WebElement result = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("com.example.app1:id/tvResult")));
            Assert.assertEquals(result.getText(), "Set data successfull");

        }
    }

}
```

I am getting an error as "**Expected condition failed: waiting for visibility of element**"

As a workaround, after the app launch if I press on Home Button->navigate to app list->launch the app->i am able to find the element and make action on it as shown below.

> Work around Code

```
public class Main {

    AndroidDriver driver = null;

    @Before
    public void main(){
        DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities();
        cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, "00757fccdb6fabc5");
        cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_NAME, "Android");
        cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APP, "C:\\Users\\kswamina\\Desktop\\zApp1\\zApp1\\zApp1\\build\\outputs\\apk\\debug\\zApp1-debug.apk");

        try {
            driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), cap);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void testClick(){
        if(driver != null){

            try {
                Thread.sleep(3000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            driver.pressKey(new KeyEvent(AndroidKey.HOME));
            driver.findElementByAccessibilityId("Apps").click();
            driver.findElementByAccessibilityId("App1").click();

            WebDriverWait wait0 = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
            wait0.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(MobileBy.id("com.example.app1:id/tvKey"))).sendKeys("MMS");

            driver.findElement(By.id("com.example.app1:id/etName")).sendKeys("VPN");
            driver.findElement(By.id("com.example.app1:id/btnStore")).click();
            WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 2);
            WebElement result = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("com.example.app1:id/tvResult")));
            Assert.assertEquals(result.getText(), "Set data successfull");

        }
    }

}
```

This is just a sample test code, i am just trying to find why i am unable to find an element. Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you share server logs for case without pressing home button

Answer (score 0):

You need provide the App package and App Activity in the desired capabilitiy.

example :

cap.setCapability(“appPackage”, “com.android.app1”);

cap.setCapability(“appActivity”, “com.android.app1.MainActivity”);